# Jquery - Select the last option in a select which is not disabled (Safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

From this `select`:

```
<select>
    <option disabled>Value 1</option>
    <option disabled>Value 2</option>
    <option>Value 3</option>
</select>
```

How I can mark the last item which is not `disabled` as *selected*?

Example of what I want to make is here:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('select option').attr('disabled', true);
    
    $('select option').each(function() {
        var currFormat = this.value;
        
        if(currFormat == '300x300' || currFormat == '400x400') {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
    
    $('select option:not(:disabled):last').prop('selected', true).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option>100x100</option>
    <option>200x200</option>
    <option>300x300</option>
    <option>400x400</option>
    <option>500x500</option>
</select>

<button>Select only the 300x300 and 400x400</button>
```

If I click on the button in Safari, the first item is still selected whereas the 400x400 item should be selected.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused based on your update to the question:   the first non-disabled option will automatically be selected by default; you don't need to do anything for that to happen.  The content of your jsfiddle do not seem to resemble the question (none of the options there are disabled.)  What are you actually asking here?

Comment: I've updated your question based on the JSFiddle and the comments you left on my answer. This should have been what your question looked like from the beginning to avoid a classic [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023 and you definitely do not need jQuery for this.

Use element properties instead of manipulating attributes dynamically. This appears to keep Safari happy.

```js
const allowed = new Set(["300x300", "400x400"]);

const options = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("option"));

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  options.forEach((option) => {
    option.disabled = !allowed.has(option.value);
  });
  const lastEnabled = options.findLast(({ disabled }) => !disabled);
  if (lastEnabled) {
    lastEnabled.selected = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<select>
    <option>100x100</option>
    <option>200x200</option>
    <option>300x300</option>
    <option>400x400</option>
    <option>500x500</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Select only the 300x300 and 400x400</button>
```

---

*jQuery answer*...

```js
const allowed = new Set(["300x300", "400x400"]);

const options = $("option");

$("button").on("click", () => {
  options.prop("disabled", function() {
    return !allowed.has(this.value);
  });
  options.filter(":not(:disabled)").last().prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option>100x100</option>
    <option>200x200</option>
    <option>300x300</option>
    <option>400x400</option>
    <option>500x500</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Select only the 300x300 and 400x400</button>
```

Comment: Sorry question is more how I can make an option `selected`.

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/o3mLfbav/ On the click of the button, the first item is still selected.

Comment: @popomomo when I run that Fiddle, the 400x400 item is selected. Why does your question say you want the first non-disabled option when the fiddle shows you targeting the last?

Comment: Possible that in Safari this behavior does not work ?

Comment: I've check in Chrome and yes it's working but not in Safari. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery here; a simple path query is sufficient:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#foo option:not([disabled])'))
```

```html
<select id="foo">
    <option disabled>Value 1</option>
    <option disabled>Value 2</option>
    <option>Value 3</option>
</select>
```